# Stripe subscriptions: how to pass customer's name and email to PaymentIntent?

Tags: javascript, php

To set up subscriptions, I am following step-by-step the instructions at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-after-payment

All is good until step 5 (Save the card): I want to save the customer's name and email there, and stripe.confirmCardPayment doesn't seem to accept it (unlike the sample as https://github.com/stripe-samples/payment-form-modal/blob/master/cards-only/client/elementsModal.js)

Even when passing such data, the Dashboard shows the customer doesn't have name and email.

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment(paymentIntent.client_secret, {
    payment_method: {
      card: card,
      billing_details: { name: content.customerName } // << WHAT I WANT
    }
    })
    .then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      var displayError = document.getElementById("card-errors");
      displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      stripePaymentHandler();
    }
});
```

How to pass the customer's name and email with stripe.confirmCardPayment?

Comment: You can check 'Saving credit card details for later' https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that I don't get the customer's email in the first place when using confirmCardPayment(paymentIntent...)